# Why does Django not load static files if DEBUG = False?

Tags: django

My CSS was not loading, and then I changed DEBUG to True, and it worked.

My problem is if I have an actual server and have DEBUG = False, the CSS wont load.

What does the DEBUG setting have to do with static files? It should load static files no matter if DEBUG is True or False.

Comment: You should be using your server to serve all the content, including static content.

Comment: you mean to say the actual server is different from the localhost server  ?

Answer (score 8):

You can serve statics in `DEBUG=False` using([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#cmdoption-runserver-insecure))(which is not recommended in Production Server):

```
python manage.py runserver --insecure
```

Also, you can use [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) to serve static content. For that you need to install it via `pip install whitenoise`, then add a new middleware in your settings, like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  # 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
  # ...
]
```

Using whitenoise is is secured and much standard for serving static files(if you don't want to use reverse proxy server)

Comment: I asked why is this behaviour ? Why not let django serve static files, no matter DEBUG is True or False ?

Comment: Because `it’s grossly inefficient and probably insecure`. (as per docs)

Comment: Not convinced, why would make an app if django wont load static files in production ?

Answer (score 2):

In debug mode, Django will serve everything, so that you don't have to bother with anything else like Apache/Nginx.

In production mode, using Python to serve static content is a waste of resources, and Django assumes you will set up a web server to serve the static content. See:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/ (for commands you will need)
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/ (for details on static files during development)

and especially

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/deployment/ (for details on static files during production)

Comment: This is like an extra overhead, to setup web server just to serve static files lol,  as I come from php background. As I said ridiculous.

Comment: If I put DEBUG = True in production, its not production server anymore lol

Comment: Indeed. Which is why no-one suggested this. Go through the last link and set up your production server properly.

Comment: This is dumb, why would I setup web server just to serve static files if I can do that easily in php ?

Comment: You can't do that in PHP. When you write PHP, Apache does it for you (though transparently). Saying Django is dumb for not doing something like PHP is like saying soup is dumb because they're hard to eat with a fork. No, it is your fault for eating soup with a fork in the first place. I said why it is so, and the first of my links says why it is so: serving static files from Python is "grossly inefficient and probably insecure. This is only intended for local development, should never be used in production".

Comment: If serving static files was web servers task as per django, why did it introduced a concept of static files in documentation ?

Comment: It's a helpful development feature. Nothing more.

Comment: No django wants a credit here lol, like they are special and they introduced a concept of static files funny lol

Comment: No-one here "invented" a concept of static files, we are merely talking about how they are served. There are valid reasons for these choices; you keep mocking them out of willful ignorance, and it only makes _yourself_ look bad. Please stop, it is embarrassing.

Comment: I am not mocking you, I am mocking the framework, the framework wont let me load static files in production lol

Comment: There is a proper procedure how you serve static files in production, Amadan has the links as well and it is well documented in the docs. If you have any programming related issue, then people can answer here, else there is no meaning of mocking a framework.

Comment: I have enough programming sense, thats why I am asking why there is an extra burden of handling static files in django, why would I follow those procedures if I can skip those in other frameworks ? Time to move on lol